# sqrt and div instructions run at same speed

Tags: algorithm, optimization, assembly, language-agnostic

I was casually reading through the intel architectures reference manual, http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr12/cos217/reading/ia32opt.pdf, and as I was reading through the instruction latency and throughput appendix, I discovered that the latency (The number of clock cycles that are required for the execution core to 
complete the execution of all of the μops that form an instruction.) for the sqrt instruction was the exact same as the latency for the divide (on page C-28) instruction--at least for some microarchitectures. The numbers were 30, 40, and 44 clock cycles, for single, double, and extended precision, respectively.

My question is how can a sqrt instruction be just as large of a processor sink as a div instruction? I have always been under the impression that sqrt instructions were costly in any language.

Comment: They probably use look-up tables somewhere

Comment: Maybe, although I don't believe that 64 bits worth of addresses hard-coded into the processor would make a manageable lookup table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, division is asymptotically of the same order  as a number of functions, including square root, which can be calculated via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method. The number of iterations of Newton's method is small because the number of correct digits doubles each time. The early iterations are cheap because you don't have to do them with full precision - you only need the accuracy you expect of the iteration - asymptotically the result is that every is about as expensive as a single full-precision division - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations

On a chip, they probably use some highly tuned special purpose method for both, but they might be the same cost if the biggest contribution to the cost is some number of passes through the chip's multiply pipeline at the end to get a full-precision result after fast table-lookup or other approximate solution.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't well known, but there are algorithms for computing square root that are just as fast as doing division in terms of shift operations.  These aren't Newton approximations.

See [(Sqrt in) Binary numeral system (base 2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29).    I first saw this in Knuth's Seminumerical Algorithms book, and used it to code sqrts on 16 bit minicomputers back in the early 1970s with the same speed as divides.  The core of the loop shifts out two bits, computes a square root bit, and repeats.  So, total shifts == number of bits, which is the same for a classic divide.

If they do divide by a shift-and-compare method on the chip, they can pretty easily implement the square root.